# Shape turns to square when trying to change color

Tags: android, android-layout

I followed some of the examples to draw a circle but when I change color the circle turns to a square. The color is applied to the view.  How do I change the actual circle with the "@+id/circle2" color and not the view that is cast that contain the circle.

circle.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval"
android:id="@+id/circle2" > >
<gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
android:angle="270"/>
 </shape>
```

This is in the main xml

```
        <View
    android:id="@+id/colordot"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="325dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
```

I cast the view that contains the circle.xml

```
    F1Color =(View) findViewById(R.id.colordot);
```

I change the color

```
F1Color.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(R_value,G_value,B_value));
```

This works well, Thank you SO

```
private void SetColorDot(int index, int i, int j, int k)

                Resources res = getResources();
        final Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(i, j, k), Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.colordot1);
        img.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `View.setBackgroundColor(color);`, this **replaces** the previous `Drawable` you had set as a background with a new `ColorDrawable`, which is why you're seeing the square shape.

One possible solution might be to change `colordot` from a `View` to an `ImageView` - which will allow you to use `setColorFilter()`. you can use your RGB color in the `ColorFilter` to recolor your circle, ie:

```
F1Color = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.colordot);
F1Color.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLACK, Color.rgb(R_value, G_value, B_value));
```

Comment: I made the changes and it turns black on setting color.

Comment: a black circle, or a black square?

Comment: Any ideas on the setting the color a shape

Comment: try playing around with the LightingColorFilter, perhaps using Color.GRAY instead of Color.BLACK will have better results. if not, I think you can also use F1Color.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(R_value, G_value, B_value), Mode.SRC_IN); which might work better